# could not read ascii file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file looks like below, I could not read the last column. How to know the delimiter?

```
data = np.genfromtxt(f,usecols=(5),delimiter=' ',dtype=float)
print data
```

text file called f:

```
   22219355 02/21/2003 10:24:31.843 -65.033577  65.429672      25.193       26.985641
   22219355 02/21/2003 10:24:31.868 -65.035101  65.429033      25.546       26.987436
   22219355 02/21/2003 10:24:31.893 -65.036626  65.428389      25.647       26.989231
   22219355 02/21/2003 10:24:31.918 -65.038151  65.427740      25.866       26.991026
   22219360 02/21/2003 10:24:32.818 -65.092890  65.402383      25.807       27.053846
   22219360 02/21/2003 10:24:32.843 -65.094410  65.401728      25.969       27.055641
   22219360 02/21/2003 10:24:32.868 -65.095928  65.401061      25.225       27.057436
   22219360 02/21/2003 10:24:32.993 -65.103518  65.397543      25.378       27.066410
   22219360 02/21/2003 10:24:33.018 -65.105038  65.396803      25.123       27.068205
   22219360 02/21/2003 10:24:33.043 -65.106558  65.396053      25.422       27.070000
   22219365 02/21/2003 10:24:33.068 -65.108078  65.395293      24.673       27.070000
   22219365 02/21/2003 10:24:33.093 -65.109599  65.394527      24.832       27.071538
   22219365 02/21/2003 10:24:33.118 -65.111119  65.393755      24.594       27.073077
   22219365 02/21/2003 10:24:33.143 -65.112639  65.392980      25.090       27.074615
   22219365 02/21/2003 10:24:33.193 -65.115677  65.391423      24.711       27.077692
```

Comment: \t possibly? Or whatever a tab char happens to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `delimiter=None`

By default, genfromtxt assumes delimiter=None, meaning that the line is split along white spaces (including tabs), and this probably suits your needs